# How to make a channel with a maximum length of one element?

Tags: rust, mutex, channel

I'm successfully using a `mpsc::channel()` to send messages from a producer thread to a consumer.

The consumer is only ever interested in the latest message.  (It uses the message from the previous check if there is no new message.)

In consequence, I'm running the consumer's `try_recv()` in a loop until it fails to get a new message, and then using the last received message, or the old one if no new messages were found.

Memory is being wasted storing old messages which the consumer will throw away.

How would I build a one-element variant of `mpsc::channel()`?

(I've considered using `sync::Mutex<Option<MyMessage>>` but it is critical that the consuming thread blocks for as little time as possible.  Also, I want ownership to pass from the producer to the consumer.)

Comment: Note that an `mpsc::channel` [holds a `Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/src/std/sync/mpsc/sync.rs.html#44), so a `sync::Mutex<Option<MyMessage>>` is no worse in that regard.

Comment: Do you also want to pass ownership of messages that the consumer will never use? Or otherwise said, would it matter if a producer overwrote a message the consumer has never seen?

Comment: @Jmb, thanks for that info.  I'm really looking for something that compiles to a cmpxchg.

Comment: @MatthieuM. No, I don't care about messages which the consumer will never use.  It's fine for the producer to overwrite message which the consumer has never seen.

Comment: @fadedbee you could use an [`AtomicPtr<Option<MyMessage>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicPtr.html) whose [`swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicPtr.html#method.swap) method should compile to an `xchg`.

Comment: In C/assembly, the producer would `malloc()` a struct, populate it and then `cmpxchg` a pointer to the new struct into a shared location.  The consumer would `cmpxchg` for a `nullptr` when it wanted to read.  If the producer received a `nullptr`, it would know the last message had been passed.  If the produce received an address, if would `free()` it.  If the consumer received a `nullptr`, it would ignore it.  If the consumer received an address, it would use it what it pointed to, and then `free()` the struct which the producer had originally malloc'd.

Comment: @Jmb Thanks, that looks like it.  If you make it an answer, I'll accept it as soon as I get the code working.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an [`AtomicPtr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicPtr.html), whose [`compare_exchange`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicPtr.html#method.compare_exchange) method should compile to a simple `cmpxchg` instruction, allowing you to store either [`std::ptr::null`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/ptr/fn.null.html) or an actual message.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few possibilities, with various trade-offs.

I'd recommend the `arc-swap` crate (see below) for a safe and fast interface, and the DIY Double Buffering approach if performance is that critical.

#### std::mpsc

There's a second option for `std::mpsc`: the `sync_channel` function creates a bounded channel, where the sender blocks when the channel is full, until the receiver picks off a message.

I do not think that it is ideal for your usecase.

#### Tokio Watch channel

The Tokio ecosystem has the [`watch`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/index.html) channel designed for the purpose of propagating configuration changes.

Unfortunately it is designed for multiple consumers, so the consumers borrow the messages: there is no transfer of ownership.

#### Arc Swap

I believe the [`arc-swap`](https://crates.io/crates/arc-swap) crate may be closer to what you need. As the name implies, it provides the moral equivalent of an `Atomic<Arc<T>>`.

You can use the `ArcSwapOption<T>` to have the equivalent of an `Atomic<Option<Arc<T>>>`, and the consumer can simply perform a `let new = atomic.swap(None);` then check if `new` is `None` (nothing new) or `Some(Arc<T>)` in which case it received an updated configuration.

Do be mindful of the cost of the dropping the previous `Arc<T>` when swapping a new one in: `free` is typically more expensive than `malloc`.

#### Back to `std`

You could use an `AtomicPtr<T>`. It'll require you to use `unsafe`, and would be a smidgen faster than `ArcSwap` by virtue of avoiding the reference counting.

It would suffer from the same drop issue, though.

#### DIY Double Buffering

You could also simply Do It Yourself. A simple double-buffering storage would work.

By storing a plain `Option<T>`, you avoid the additional extra allocation (and thus extra de-allocation), at the cost of making the check itself slower -- as you may now need to check *both* buffers. It may be possible to check a single buffer, not clear.